# select case doesn't work for one of the values

Tags: sql-server

Why doesn't my 'XXX' value work in this select case statement.  I want it to give back a blank, but it gives back the same string as the 'RNC'.

```
SELECT SHORT_DESC =  
      CASE   
         WHEN MAIL_CODE1 <> 'RNC' THEN SHORT_DESC
         WHEN MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX' THEN ' '
         ELSE 'Request No Contact'    
      END 
FROM (select 1 dummy) dummy
left join TMS_MAILING_1 m ON m.MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX'--${MailCode}
  GROUP BY SHORT_DESC, MAIL_CODE1;
```

Comment: I mean, `'XXX'` is not equal to `'RNC'`, so the first condition is true and returns the value specified there

Comment: this is simple logic. MAIL_CODE1 <> 'RNC' which means that if  MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX' the first condition will be met... so...

Comment: I see that, but how do i get it to return the values i need to display.  thanks for you help

Comment: i thought it was simple logic so it should give me back the values that I am looking to display.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
SELECT SHORT_DESC =  
      CASE   
         WHEN MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX' THEN ' '
         WHEN MAIL_CODE1 <> 'RNC' THEN SHORT_DESC
         ELSE 'Request No Contact'    
      END 
FROM (SELECT 1 dummy) dummy
    LEFT JOIN TMS_MAILING_1 m ON m.MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX'--${MailCode}
GROUP BY SHORT_DESC, MAIL_CODE1;
```

Remember there is a condition validation order in a `CASE` statement, starting from the first and going down to the last.

The first valid condition is returned, which in your case is `TRUE`.

You should always check for equality first and then non-equality.

Also, your query logic seems a bit strange. I'd rewrite the query like:

```
DECLARE @PARAM NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'XXX'--${MailCode}

SELECT
    SHORT_DESC = CASE
        WHEN MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX'
            THEN ''
        WHEN MAIL_CODE1 <> 'RNC'
            THEN SHORT_DESC
        ELSE 'Request No Contact'
    END
FROM TMS_MAILING_1
WHERE MAIL_CODE1 = @PARAM
```

**For testing purposes**, you can use the below code and just change the value of the `@PARAM` variable to see how the query would behave based on your input.

```
DECLARE @PARAM NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'XXX'--${MailCode}

SELECT
    SHORT_DESC = CASE
        WHEN MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX'
            THEN ''
        WHEN MAIL_CODE1 <> 'RNC'
            THEN 'SHORT_DESC'
        ELSE 'Request No Contact'
    END
FROM (SELECT @PARAM AS MAIL_CODE1) X
WHERE MAIL_CODE1 = @PARAM
```

Comment: I tried it and it still gives the RNC results.  the mail_code1 is being passed as a variable to look up a value in the tms_mailing_1 table.  However, the 'RNC' and the 'XXX'  will be passed but the user wants it to have the values above because they are not in the table.  Does that make any sense...thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @user2831724 Well, what are you passing then? Are you passing 'XXX' ? If the value you are passing is anything different than `XXX` then the 2nd condition will be evaluated to true.

Comment: I can pass either "RNC", "XXX", or any valid codes that ARE in the table which there are 5 valid codes in the table.

Comment: In this case, I am passing one of the valid values in the table and it return's the string 'Do Not Call'....
SELECT SHORT_DESC =  
      CASE   
         WHEN MAIL_CODE1 = 'XXX' THEN ' '
         WHEN MAIL_CODE1 <> 'RNC' THEN SHORT_DESC
         ELSE 'Request No Contact'    
      END 
FROM (SELECT 1 dummy) dummy
    LEFT JOIN TMS_MAILING_1 m ON m.MAIL_CODE1 = 'AFC'--${MailCode}
GROUP BY SHORT_DESC, MAIL_CODE1;

Comment: @user2831724 For somewhat reason your first condition is not evaluated correctly (as true). I wouldn't blame the query for that and I'd investigate in other places. Make sure you pass the query the value that you're expecting (maybe use Profiler to catch that).

Comment: @user2831724 WELL, you're Passing `AFC` which is not equal to `XXX` and the 2nd condition in the `CASE` statement is evaluated to `TRUE`, because `RNC` is different than `AFC`. **Look that you are filtering by `MAIL_CODE1 = 'AFC'` in your LEFT JOIN**